Prompted for password after updating sudoers with NOPASSWD
My user is saroh and I need to be able to start the service crs_svc as user notify without being prompted for password.
The command to accopmlish this is
sudo -u notify /bin/systemctl start crs_svc

To be exempted from authorizing I added this line in the very end of my sudoers:
saroh ALL=(notify) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl start crs_svc

However when trying to run the command I get this
$ sudo -u notify /bin/systemctl start crs_svc
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ====
Authentication is required to start 'crs_svc.service'.
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 1.  hb
 2.  saroh
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2):

What could be the issue?

There is no sudoers-related issue here – you did in fact run the systemctl command without sudo prompting you for a password. Now it's systemctl itself that prompts you for a password; the text of the prompt is very distinctively looking like the polkit-tty-agent prompt that is shown by systemctl, and completely different from a typical sudo prompt.
Systemctl is showing you this prompt because only root is allowed to start/stop system services by default, and the 'notify' user is not root and therefore not exempt from authorizing either.
In other words, your configuration works fine, but sudo'ing to the 'notify' user is the wrong plan to start with. By default, the only user that is actually exempt is root, so the simplest way to make this command passwordless would be to sudo to 'root' instead of 'notify'.

/etc/sudoers
saroh ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl start crs_svc

$ sudo [-u root] systemctl start crs_svc


Alternatively, it is also possible to configure systemd's authorization mechanism (polkit) to actually make certain users exempt from "admin" authentication. This should be applied directly to your own account – applying it to the 'notify' account would be an unnecessary detour.

/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/crs.rules
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (subject.user == "saroh" &&
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units" &&
        action.lookup("unit") == "crs_svc.service")
    {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
})

$ systemctl start crs_svc (without sudo)



Keep in mind that the user that the service will run under has no relationship with the user who calls 'systemctl start' – no matter who calls systemctl, the service daemon will always be run with the user account specified as User= in the .service unit.
The systemctl command doesn't directly run anything; it only sends a "Start service" call to the service manager, which then sets up the service's environment from zero (nothing is inherited from systemctl at all).
(This is also the reason why systemctl has its own authorization prompt – it's not the user-switching that needs permissions, but the sending of the "StartUnit" call to systemd that does.)
So if the service process needs to be run as the 'notify' user, then that needs to be specified as
[Service]
User=notify

in the .service file, and the initial answer still applies – the "start" command still needs to be sudo'd to root (or not sudo'd at all, if you use the polkit method); there is no need to sudo it to the 'notify' user.

Thanks for your comprehensive answer, @grawity_u1686. However I need crs_svc to be run exactly by notify. This command should be a part of a GitLab CI/CD pipeline, and should be run on the production server through ssh. The user notify does not have login permission on the production server so I need to use another user for logging in, such as saroh. This is why I need the service to be started by notify and without password.

Is notify the SSH user, or is it the user that the daemon is supposed to be running as?

notify is intended only to run the daemon. The SSH user is saroh.

Then you're searching in the wrong direction – the user that invokes systemctl has nothing to do with the user that the process will be run as. No matter who calls systemctl, the process will always be run under the account specified as [Service] User= in the service definition, so it is pointless to sudo the systemctl call to that user since that only controls who issues the "Start service" command to systemd.

Thanks a lot for pointing this out. I do not have much experience in this field so could not see the issue.
